# Why use class names that describe the presentation is not recommended?

Tags: css

I am reading CSS Cookbook by Christopher Schmitt. He says

> Using class names that describe the presentation, as I did in this
>   Solution, is not recommended.

But why? It can save time and effort when the same situation need to be addressed multiple times. Like **Twitter-Bootstrap** use class to describe the presentation all the time.

Twitter-Bootstrap creates so many classes for different purpuse. Like `col-sm-1` OR `col-lg-offset-1`. It uses class to describe the presentation.

Below is the Code in book as *BAD* example.

```
.leftFloat {
float: left
}

.rightFloat {
float: right 
}
```

Comment: Because as soon as you style the `.leftFloat` elements differently, and they're no longer `float: left` the name no longer makes sense, and is actively confusing. So you have to rename the class. And update the class-names of every element that calls that class. Or you have elements with thirty classes, each class doing one specific thing, and then you're fighting specificity and you've made no saving by using CSS, and you might as well just inline styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that wie try to seperate content and presentation. In theory you should be able to swap out the CSS and go from a mobile site to the desktop version, a print version,  an app version etc.

When you have classes like

```
.italicbold {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

you could as well move that into a `style` attribute.

The rationale is that today web developers have to maintain multiple versions and that redundancy sucks. If your mobile site has different markup, there are two places you'll need to change.
However there are many reasons why something that's bold on the desktop shouldn't be on mobile (+ hover effects etc). You could of course overwrite ".bold" to apply an underline effect in the mobile CSS, but that will make your code really hard to read (B/C of remembering what everything really does in which case).

Comment: then do you think the way bootstrap doing is a bad practice?

Comment: Bootsrap is a CSS framework, there isn't really an alternative there. Plus those "practices" are just practices and when you don't want to you just don't follow. But I guess yes, bootstrap contradicts this paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the title of the class should apply to the type of code being changed, not the nature of the changes.

For instance, if you have an HTML class called content and you then wish to float it left you will have something like:

```
<div class="content">
<h2>London</h2>
</div>
```

Now if you wish to make this float left, you could say CSS like:

```
.content{float: left;}
```

The more logical train of thought is; lets take the class "content", and make it float left.  The directionality of the changes is inverted.

Additionally, how (using your scheme) could you make multiple changes:  Say I want my content to float left and be bold: Easy

```
<div class="content">
<h2>London</h2>
</div> 
.content{float: left;font-weight: bold;}
```

How would you name the class both float left and bold... or any of 100 other things.

Comment: Twitter-Bootstrap creates so many classes for different purpuse. Like `col-sm-1` OR `col-lg-offset-1`. It uses class to describe the presentation.